# Can not connect to database inside of docker container providing correct user and password

Tags: docker-compose, mariadb

I have this setup for docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: db
    image: mariadb:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
    - mariadb-travian:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - travian-network
volumes:
  mariadb-travian:
networks:
  travian-network:
```

.env file looks like this:

```
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_PORT=3306
MYSQL_DATABASE=mardiadb-travian
MYSQL_PASSWORD=TAQ59WqPeoGOTFv
ROOT_PASSWORD=CvlLpyqyeAzTg6V
MYSQL_USER=admin
MYSQL_VERSION=10.5.0
DATABASE_URL="mysql://admin:TAQ59WqPeoGOTFv@mariadb:3306/mardiadb-travian?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5.0"
```

After running docker-compose up everything runs perfectly but I'm unable to connect to the database inside of the container:

```
docker exec -it db bash
mysql -u admin -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

**EDIT: tried running same setup on macos and it worked fine, but on ubuntu doesn't work**

Comment: Hi, could you provide more details about application which trying to connect to database. May be you forgot to change databse url

Comment: @Farfetch'd as you can see I'm trying to connect through docker container, so it doesn't matter...

Comment: tested with `podman run --rm --env MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=CvlLpyqyeAzTg6V --env MARIADB_USER=admin --env MARIADB_PASSWORD=TAQ59WqPeoGOTFv --name ml -d  mariadb:latest` , `podman exec -ti ml mariadb -u admin -pTAQ59WqPeoGOTFv` and it connected. tested 10.11.3 and 11.0.2 (after repulling latest). It looks like it user/pass was changed after initialization occured.